# Problem with finding the fewest number of guesses in Hi-Lo game

Tags: java

I am having problem with finding the fewest number of guesses that took the player to find the answer
i thought that i can create an array and store all the values but i dont know how many times the program will run so i cant create an array without setting size, and am trying to find a way without using list .

```
public class HiLo {
    private static int []result =new int [7];
    private static int []temp =new int [3];
    
    public static void choices() {
    
        StdOut.println("****************************");
        StdOut.println("* 1. Play a round of HiLo. *");
        StdOut.println("* 2. View game statistics. *");
        StdOut.println("* 3. Quit the game         *");
        StdOut.println("****************************");
        StdOut.println("Enter your choice: ");
            int choice=StdIn.readInt();//reads player choice
            if (choice==1) {
                choice1();
                
            }
            if (choice==2) {
                
            double d=result[2]; //making guesses from int to double
            double c=result[3]; //making rounds from int to double  
            StdOut.println("Rounds Won: "+result[0]);
            StdOut.println("Rounds Quited: "+result[1]);
            StdOut.println("Guesses: "+result[2]);
            StdOut.println("Rounds: "+result[3]);
            StdOut.println("Most guesses: "+result[4]);
            StdOut.println("Fewest guesses: "+result[5]);
            double average=(d/c);//average  guesses 
            
            StdOut.println("Average guesses: "+average);
            choices();
            }
            if (choice==3) {
                StdOut.println("Thank you for playing HiLo.");
            }
            else {
                StdOut.println("You must enter a number between 1 and 3 to indicate your selection.\r\n");
                choices();
            }
    }

    
    public static void choice1( ) {
        result[3]++;//loop for adding total rounds
        int randomNumber=StdRandom.uniform(1, 100);//the random number that the pc choose
        String a="0";//starting value of 
        int guesses=0;//starting value of guesses this round
        StdOut.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ");
        
        while (Integer.parseInt(a)!=randomNumber) {
              
         a=StdIn.readString();//reads number or "quit" from user
           if (a.equals("quit")) {//if quit 
                StdOut.print("Round "+ result[3] +" has been terminated. The number was "+randomNumber);
                StdOut.println("");
                temp[2]=result[2]-guesses;//removes the guesses used in this round from the total guesses
                result[2]=temp[2];//storing the new guesses in the array
                result[1] ++;//storing the times a player quited
           
            choices();
            }
        if (Integer.parseInt(a)>randomNumber) {
          StdOut.println("Your guess is high. ");       
         
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(a)<randomNumber) {
          StdOut.println("Your guess is low. ");            
    
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(a)!=randomNumber) {
            StdOut.print("Guess again or enter 'quit' to end the round:");
            guesses++;//adding guesses for this round
              result[2]++;//storing the times the player guessed
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(a)==randomNumber) {
            guesses++;//adding guesses for this round
            result[2]++;//storing the times the player guessed  
            StdOut.print("Congratulations! You won round " + result[3] +" in "+guesses+" guesses.");
              StdOut.println("");  
             temp[0]=guesses;
             if(temp[0]>=result[4]) {//comparing the guesses this round with the most guesses
                 result[4]=temp[0];//if guesses this round is bigger than the "MOST GUESSES" value then it replace the "MOST GUESSES"
             }
// HERE I HAVE TO WRITE A WAY  TO FIND THE FEWEST
             temp[1]=result[2]-temp[0];//all guesses - minus this round guesses
             
                
             }
              
              result[0]++;//storing the times a player won the game
              choices();
      
        }    

         
          
         
          
         
        
        }
        
        
            
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StdOut.println("****************************");
        StdOut.println("*          HiLo            *");
        StdOut.println("*                          *");
        StdOut.println("*          NAME            *");
        StdOut.println("*                          *");
        StdOut.println("*           ID             *");
        StdOut.println("****************************");
        choices();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you actually need to store the guesses? Can you simply count how many guesses were made? If you want to do it per round, and there are infinite rounds, then a list or map would be your best options

Comment: How about using a static variable that you would initialize with a big value, then update if the number of guesses is inferior to that value ?

Comment: Working with Dominique's comment you can either set the count to int.MAX_VALUE and have a counter of number of attempts made for each (game/round?). The static member storing the lowest number of attempts is updated upon completing each game/round if the number of attempts is lower than the lowest recorded count. The attempt counter is reset after that. No list should be required if all you need is the all-time low count.

Answer (score 0):

Since your not displaying their guesses later I would not keep track of them, but if you have to you could try using a LinkedList.